# How to show all rows and all columns of matrix A with print(DataFrame(A))?

Tags: python, matrix

I have a 15 by 15 matrix A, created using a code like the following:

```
for i in range(14):
    for j in range(14):
        A[i,j]=some number
```

By typing print(DataFrame(A)), the result doesn't show all columns. In particular, Column 5-9 are shown as "...". How could I show all columns of this matrix?  Thanks!

Comment: "I have a 15 by 15 matrix A" This could mean many things. It is not useful unless you show us actual code. Please read [ask] and https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel Thanks! I will try to improve the question.

Comment: How do you run your program? Are you using the command line? Or are you using IDLE or some other editor? It sounds like the tool you are using is eliding the output with the "...". You may need to write a for loop to manually print out the matrix in the format you want.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice Thanks! I'm doing it in Pycharm.

Comment: Are you using numpy?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice Yes.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice I tried np.set_printoptions(threshold=sys.maxsize), and it didn't work.

Comment: What does "it didn't work" mean? Please refer to the links Karl gave in the first comment.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice Thanks! I meant column 5-9 are still missing. But I just found the solution: print(DataFrame(A).to_string()) works.